# Localhost install stuck at 57% Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Tags: magento2, installation, localhost, xampp

Everything on the installation is fine until this part. It has been 1 hour it has been sitting at 53% and no errors in the console.

I am using Xampp.

Comment: Hello, Are you using Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

The Magento 2 setup can take a while. If you don't manually adjust your webserver (Apache, nginx, lighttpd, etc.) settings to allow for long running scripts, eventually the webserver will quit waiting for a response and things will hang. I've noticed this when doing the web installer while using the sample data.

The alternative is to use the CLI installer. It has all the same options to configure; however, it shouldn't have a time constraint like a webserver does. It's a pain and requires shell (ssh) access, but it's best for long running processes.

As for pages not working, you need to check your logs. You can start with the Magento log directory; however, that probably won't have anything in it. Next I would look at your PHP logs and webserver  logs. There's probably A PHP error occurring causing the script to fail, giving you a white screen.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this issue, but yes I was using Xampp. I ended up using a different machine as it may have been a performance issue. However, now I have it installed, it went through no problem (install successful). However when I now go to the admin URL (using the one setup up during install).

It only goes to a blank page (white, nothing showing).

Comment: Solved! Magento up and running perfect. Thank you